# Google Calendar API event time update without changing date

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, zoho

Is there any way to update the current time of an event without changing the current date using google calendar API with python?

I'm working on a project that sync zoho people calendar with google calendar and I've to update the  all day Leave event and set a duration of 9 hours (9AM to 6PM). I've done the synching part and all and I'm able to change the time and duration also, but I can't change the time without changing the event date [datetime.now()]. What I want is to keep the date of the event as it is and just change the time of event.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question include your code and describe the issues you are having ideally a [example]

Answer (score 0):

Using [gcsa](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/google-calendar-simple-api/), this would look like:

```
from gcsa.google_calendar import GoogleCalendar
from datetime import datetime, time

gc = GoogleCalendar('path/to/credentials.json')

event = gc.get_event('event_id')
event.start = datetime.combine(event.start, time(hour=9))
event.end = datetime.combine(event.end, time(hour=18))

gc.update_event(event)
```